# Instagram API doesn't load embed.js outside Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, instagram, instagram-api, embedding

I'm doing tests with social networks APIs, and I'm getting a weird behaviour with Instagram.

What I want is to embed Instagram's feed for my account into a website. I started the website on Visual Studio and the embedding works pretty well (considering that it is very difficult for something to go well with the Instagram API).

But when I try outside VS, crash downloading **embed.js**, which I assume is a parser for embedding Instagram's code.

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
      var igToken = 'xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
      var igApiTimeline = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=';
      var igApiPhoto = 'https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=http://instagr.am/p/';
      var link, url;

      $.get(igApiTimeline + igToken, function (r1) {
          for (var i = 0; i < r1.data.length; i++) {
            link = r1.data[i].link;
            url = igApiPhoto + link.substr(link.indexOf('/p/') + 3);
            $.get(url, function (r2) {
                $('.ig-posts').append(r2.html);
            });
        }
    });
  </script>
  <div class="ig-posts" style="width: 380px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why it only works in VS?

Comment: What do you mean by “crash”?

Comment: Well, the call _file://www.instagram.com/embed.js_ returns code _(failed)_ on Chrome.

Comment: Ah, that’s why. You need to serve your content over HTTP with server software. The file protocol file:// is subject to a lot of restrictions. VS is serving over HTTP behind the scenes for you.

Comment: I understand what you said, but I'm clueless in how to solve it. Do I need a HTTP server like **node.js** to execute it? Because I can't change that call, Instagram's API makes it internally.